# Is $\binom{52}{n}\cdot\binom{52-n}{n}$ maximised by $n=\frac{52}{3}$? If so why?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

I've been thinking a lot about cards, and recently about the combination of combination of hands....if you drew $n$ cards from a deck of $52$, and then drew another $n$ cards, how many combinations are there?

The number of combinations [appears](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2852chose%20n%29*%28%2852-n%29chose%20n%29) to peak at about $1\times10^{23}$ so I threw in my best guess at the peak number, 17, I realised that it would have to be the midpoint between the maximal of $\binom{52}{n}$ and $\binom{52-n}{n}$, which is going to be $\frac{26+13}{2}=17\frac13$ or $\frac{52}{3}$. Putting that in gives me $1.01446\times10^{23}$!

But all of this is from intuition, and I have no reason to believe this holds on all cases, nor do I know of the general case.

Is that number the maximising number? If so why, and is there a general case?

My guess at a general solution would be something like:
$$\prod_{i=0}^n\binom{m-i\cdot n}{n}\text{is maximised by }\begin{cases}\frac{m}{T_n(i+1)+1} & \text{if } i=0\\ \frac{m}{T_n(i)+1} & \text{if } i>0\end{cases}$$

But I've not formal Mathematics knowledge (just University level physics) so I'm not certain. Am I right? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us define $\binom{n}{k}$ for non-integer $n$ and $k$ by:

$$ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n-k+1)\Gamma(k+1)} $$

where $\Gamma(n) = \int_0^\infty x^{n-1} e^{-x} dx$ is the analytical continuation of the factorial (with $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$ for integer $n$). We must do this because the factorial function is not actually defined on the integers. One way to define it is the Gamma function, which matches up with the factorial for integer arguments. Now that we have the Gamma function, our problem reduces to calclus.

Then we have that:

$$ \binom{52}{n} \binom{52-n}{n} $$
$$ \frac{\Gamma(53)}{\Gamma(53-n)\Gamma(n+1)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(53-n)}{\Gamma(53-2n)\Gamma(n+1)}$$
$$ \frac{\Gamma(53)^2}{\Gamma(53-2n)\Gamma(n+1)^2}$$

The numerator is a large number ($52!^2$). So let us worry about the denominator instead. The larger the denominator is, the smaller the fraction will be. To maximize the fraction, we should minimize the denominator. So:

$$ 0 = \frac{d}{dn} \Gamma(53-2n)\Gamma(n+1)^2 $$
$$ 0 = -2\Gamma^\prime(53-2n)\Gamma(n+1)^2 + 2\Gamma^\prime(n+1)\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(53-2n) $$
$$ \Gamma^\prime(53-2n)\Gamma(n+1) = \Gamma^\prime(n+1)\Gamma(53-2n) $$

Which looks extremely ugly. One obvious way they could be equal is if $n+1 = 53-2n$, because then, by simple substitution, the two sides are equal. Solving for $n$, we get $n = \frac{52}{3}$.

Comment: I like  the cut o' your gib, matey.

Comment: Yes, the numerator is a large number, but the important fact is that it does not depend on $n$.  The result, which is correct,  would be the same if the numerator was $1$ (or $10^{-100}$)$

Answer (score 5):

Let $a_n$ be your product of binomial coefficients. It is clear that $a_n$ starts out small.

We calculate $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. Looks bad at first, but there is a tremendous amount of cancellation, and after a while we find that
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(52-2n)(52-2n-1)}{(n+1)^2}.$$

We can now use a little algebra to find out where the  function 
$$f(t)=\frac{(52-2t)(52-2t-1)}{(t+1)^2}$$
is greater than $1$, and where it is less than $1$. This turns quickly into a problem about a quadratic. 
We get equality at roughly $16.8$. So for $n\le 16$, $a_{n+1}$ is "better" than $a_n$. The maximum value of $a_n$ is therefore at $n=17$.

**Details:** We have 
$$a_n=\frac{52!}{n!(52-n)!}\frac{(52-n)!}{(n!)(52-2n)!}=\frac{52!}{n!n! (52-2n)!}.$$
Mechanically, it follows that 
$$a_{n+1}= \frac{52!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!(50-2n)!}.$$
Divide the second by the first. We get 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n!n!(52-2n)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!(50-2n)!}.$$
Now $(n+1)!=n!(n+1)$ and $(52-2n)!=(52-2n)(52-2n-1)(50-2n)!$, and we have our simplified ration.

Comment: Since we are taking a ratio, the original expression is at a (local) maximum if the ratio before is greater than one and the ratio after is less than one.  Therefore, instead of solving for where $f(t)$ is increasing or decreasing, we should look at where it is equal to $1$.  Since the top terms are close to equal, the answer will be very close to where $(52-2t)\approx t+1$

Comment: $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ is sort of the rate of change of the combinations as $n$ increases...right? So when it's greater than 1, it's increasing. [wolfram|alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2852%E2%88%92t%29%2F%28%28t%2B1%29%5E2%29+%3E1%3Bt%3E0) says this is for $t\approx5.79726$, so for the first 5 products out combinations are increasing? What about our choice of $n$ in the original equation?

Comment: Also I'd be ridiculously interested in how you got the expression for $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$.

Comment: @Pureferret: As Aaron says, we are interested in where $f(t) \gt 1$.  When $t=17, f(t)=\frac{18\cdot 17}{18^2}$, just barely less than $1$, so we would expect $t=17$ to be the maximum of the original function.

Comment: I will add details. Slightly unpleasant typing!

Comment: @RossMillikan after André's the edit, I will believe that! Thanks!

Comment: Since your background is in physics, it might be useful to note that the "as nearly equal as possible" in user14111's comment seems to be connected to the law of equipartition in statistical mechanics.  Or is that what guided your intuition in the first place?

Comment: @AndreasBlass of all the concepts in physics I never grasped the equipartition theorem, despite following most of the maths behind it. Logically it makes sense that neither deal of a hand is special, so all should have "as nearly equal as possible" a number of cards.

Comment: @user14111 how do you stipulate "as nearly equal as possible" mathematically? By that logic, my 'magic number' is $t=26$ not $17$

Comment: @Pureferret: Your original expression is about dividing the deck into $3$ parts.

Comment: @AndreasBlass ...I am? I only deal two hands: one from $\binom{52}{n}$ and one from $\binom{52-n}{n}$ (with probably some cards left over that I don't care about, right now). Have I formulated my question wrongly?

Comment: You are dealing with $3$ hands: the cards you left behind when you chose $52-n$, and then the two hands that the $52-n$ were divided into.

Comment: @Pureferret I agree with Andre; you mention only two subsets but the leftovers form a third subset.  So an equivalent and more symmetrical description of the problem concerns partitioning the deck into $3$ subsets.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I see it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Hope I'm not too late to the party. Let's consider logarithms since they are monotonically increasing and can do interesting things to products. Log of a product is a sum of logs: $$\log\left(\prod_{\forall i}a_i\right) = \sum_{\forall i}\log(a_i)$$ And the log of a factorial is a sum which can be approximated (the typical calculus rectangle area estimates) with an integral of the log function. Then we want to differentiate and set equal 0. The derivative of the integral of a log takes us back to log so using this approach we should be ending up with an equation involving a few logarithm terms instead which we can then solve for numerically or try and further use log-laws upon.